# Modern way to filter STL container?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Coming back to C++ after years of C# I was wondering what the modern - read: C++11 - way of filtering an array would be, i.e. how can we achieve something similar to this Linq query:

```
var filteredElements = elements.Where(elm => elm.filterProperty == true);
```

In order to filter a vector of elements (`strings` for the sake of this question)?

I sincerely hope the old STL style algorithms (or even extensions like `boost::filter_iterator`)  requiring *explicit methods* to be defined are superseded by now?

Comment: Does this retrieve all elements that have `filterProperty` set to `true`?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Some generic filter criterion..

Comment: There are also some libraries which try to emulate the LINQ methods of .NET: [Linq++](https://github.com/hjiang/linqxx/wiki) and [cpplinq](http://cpplinq.codeplex.com/). I haven't worked with them but my guess would be that they support STL containers.

Comment: You should be more clear about what you want, as the set of people competent at both C++ and C#  is small.  Describe what you want it to do.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

See the example from cplusplus.com for [`std::copy_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/):

```
std::vector<int> foo = {25,15,5,-5,-15};
std::vector<int> bar;

// copy only positive numbers:
std::copy_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::back_inserter(bar), [](int i){return i>=0;} );
```

`std::copy_if` evaluates the lambda expression for every element in `foo` here and if it returns `true` it copies the value to `bar`.

The `std::back_inserter` allows us to actually insert new elements at the end of `bar` (using `push_back()`) with an iterator without having to resize it to the required size first.

Comment: Is this really the closest to LINQ that C++ has to offer? This is eager (IOW not lazy), and very verbose.

Comment: @usr Its IMO syntactic sugar, a simple for loop does the job aswell (and often allows one to avoid copying).

Comment: The OPs example does not use any LINQ syntactic sugar. The benefits are lazy evaluation and composability.

Comment: @usr Which can still be achieved by a simple for-loop easily, `std::copy_if` is not more than a for-loop

Comment: @Paranaix Everything can be said to be just syntactic sugar over assembly. The point is, not to write for loops, when an algorithm can be clearly composed in a readable way using primitive operations (like filter). Many languages offer such feature - in C++ unfortunately it's still kludgy.

Comment: Assembly is just syntactic sugar over machine code.

Answer (score 128):

In C++20, use filter view from the ranges library: (requires `#include <ranges>`)

```
// namespace views = std::ranges::views;
vec | views::filter([](int a){ return a % 2 == 0; })
```

lazily returns the even elements in `vec`.

(See [[range.adaptor.object]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptor.object#4) and [[range.filter]](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter))

---

This is already supported by GCC 10 ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/24eYhzhquEfSxm4S)).  For Clang and older versions of GCC, the original range-v3 library can be used too, with `#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>` (or `#include <range/v3/all.hpp>`) and the `ranges::views` namespace instead of `std::ranges::views` ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ErfKZItIZ0OhY38s)).

Comment: You should provide the #include and use namespace needed for your answer to compile. Also, what compiler supports this as of today ?

Comment: @gsimard Better now?

Comment: If anyone tries to do this in macOS: As of May 2020, [libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx2a_status.html) does not support this.

Comment: This needs to be marked as the answer as of late 2021. A far more concise (and arguably *very* functional: the pipe operator is used in Haskell too) way of filtering things.

Comment: What does it actually return? `auto` is okay but I have to pass it to a function.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam [According to GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/u3YyVwBPLcGqBOyh), it returns `std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::ref_view<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, main()::<lambda(int)> >`.  I guess I would just make the function a template ...

Comment: @L.F. I know that but compilers like GCC like to reverse all aliases and stuff, so, I don't this is the right one. I'd expect it's something like `std::range`. I'll try to use `std::range` and see if it gets cast but yeah it's becoming a template otherwise.

Answer (score 79):

A more efficient approach, if you don't actually need a new copy of the list, is [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), which actually removes the elements from the original container.

Comment: @ATV I like `remove_if` in particular because it's the way to use filter in the presence of mutation, which is faster than copying a whole new list. If I was doing filter in C++, I'd use this over `copy_if`, so I think it adds.

Comment: For vector, at least, `remove_if` doesn't change the `size()`. [You'll need to chain it with `erase` for that](http://cpp.sh/42g7w).

Comment: @rampion Yeah.. erase/remove. Another beauty that frequently makes me feel like I'm punching holes in a tape when working in C++ (as opposed to modern languages) these days  ;-)

Comment: The explicit erase is a feature. You do not have to erase in all cases. Sometimes the iterators are enough to continue. In such cases an implicit erase would produce unnecessary overhead. Furthermore, not every container is resizable. std::array for example has no erase method at all.

Comment: @rampion A replacement for your dead link is probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30616738/9352077).

Answer (score 27):

I think [`Boost.Range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) deserves a mention too. The resulting code is pretty close to the original:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>

// ...

using boost::adaptors::filtered;
auto filteredElements = elements | filtered([](decltype(elements)::value_type const& elm)
    { return elm.filterProperty == true; });
```

The only downside is having to explicitly declare the lambda's parameter type. I used decltype(elements)::value_type because it avoids having to spell out the exact type, and also adds a grain of genericity. Alternatively, with C++14's polymorphic lambdas, the type could be simply specified as auto:

```
auto filteredElements = elements | filtered([](auto const& elm)
    { return elm.filterProperty == true; });
```

filteredElements would be a range, suitable for traversal, but it's basically a view of the original container. If what you need is another container filled with copies of the elements satisfying the criteria (so that it's independent from the lifetime of the original container), it could look like:

```
using std::back_inserter; using boost::copy; using boost::adaptors::filtered;
decltype(elements) filteredElements;
copy(elements | filtered([](decltype(elements)::value_type const& elm)
    { return elm.filterProperty == true; }), back_inserter(filteredElements));
```

Answer (score 15):

My suggestion for C++ equivalent of C#

```
var filteredElements = elements.Where(elm => elm.filterProperty == true);
```

Define a template function to which you pass a lambda predicate to do the filtering. The template function returns the filtered result. eg:

```
template<typename T>
vector<T> select_T(const vector<T>& inVec, function<bool(const T&)> predicate)
{
  vector<T> result;
  copy_if(inVec.begin(), inVec.end(), back_inserter(result), predicate);
  return result;
}
```

to use - giving a trivial examples:

```
std::vector<int> mVec = {1,4,7,8,9,0};

// filter out values > 5
auto gtFive = select_T<int>(mVec, [](auto a) {return (a > 5); });

// or > target
int target = 5;
auto gt = select_T<int>(mVec, [target](auto a) {return (a > target); });
```

Answer (score 15):

Improved [pjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5027211/pjm) code following [underscore-d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2757035/underscore-d) suggestions:

```
template <typename Cont, typename Pred>
Cont filter(const Cont &container, Pred predicate) {
    Cont result;
    std::copy_if(container.begin(), container.end(), std::back_inserter(result), predicate);
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> myVec = {1,4,7,8,9,0};

auto filteredVec = filter(myVec, [](int a) { return a > 5; });
```

Comment: Just written exaclty the same, then found yours.  Cheers.