# How to efficiently delete elements from vector c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector of pair of vectors(V1,V2) called pairV1V2 of the following form:

```
(1,2,3),(938,462,4837) -> (V1,V2)
(3,9,13),(938,0472,944)
(81,84,93),(938,84,845)
```

Then I need to retain the following:

```
(1,2,3),(938,462,4837) -> (V1,V2)
(3,9,13),(938,0472,944)
(81,84,93),(84,845)
```

I need to start scanning pairV1V2 from the beginning and where ever any two V1's are not equal, there I need to delete the intersecting elements from V2. I wrote the following code for doing same. However, my code turns out to be very inefficient as my vector pairV1V2 is big and it has many elements in V2 (about a billion).

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<unsigned>, std::vector<unsigned> > > pairV1V2;
    std::vector<std::pair <std::vector<unsigned>,std::vector<unsigned> > >::iterator itm2,lm2=pairV1V2.end();
    for(std::vector<std::pair <std::vector<unsigned>,std::vector<unsigned> > >::iterator itm=pairV1V2.begin(), lm=pairV1V2.end(); itm!=lm; ++itm)
    {
        //Outer values
        vector<unsigned> outerV1=(*itm).first;
        vector<unsigned> outerV2=(*itm).second;
        sort(outerV2.begin(), outerV2.end());
        itm2=itm;
        itm2++;
        for(itm2;itm2!=lm2;++itm2)
        {
            vector<unsigned> innerV1=(*itm2).first;
            vector<unsigned> innerV2=(*itm2).second;
            vector<unsigned> setDiffV1;
            std::set_difference(innerV1.begin(), innerV1.end(), outerV1.begin(), outerV1.end(),
                                                      std::inserter(setDiffV1, setDiffV1.end()));            
            if(setDiffV1.size()==0) //check whether any two V1's are different
            {                 
                sort(innerV2.begin(), innerV2.end());
                if((itm->second.size()!=0)&&(itm2->second.size()!=0)){                                
                    std::vector<unsigned> delIntersectingElem;
                    std::set_intersection(outerV2.begin(),outerV2.end(),innerV2.begin(), innerV2.end(),
                              std::back_inserter(delIntersectingElem));

                   if(delIntersectingElem.size()!=0) //if there are intersecting V2's
                   {                    
                        for(std::vector<unsigned>::iterator its=(itm2->second).begin(),ls=(itm2->second).end();its!=ls;)
                        { 
                            //if *its is present in delIntersectingElem then delete it.
                            if(!(std::find(delIntersectingElem.begin(), delIntersectingElem.end(), (*its)) == delIntersectingElem.end()))
                            {
                                (itm2->second).erase(its); //delete intersecting elements from inner v2
                                ls--;
                            }else{
                                ++its;
                            }
                        }                    
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help me in improving my present code -- it gives the correct answer (In the example I might have missed a few case for brevity-- but the code handles all of them) but is extremely slow (as diagonalised by perf). I'll be grateful if improvements are suggestion in my present piece of code. However, if the logic of the two codes are same, then a new algorithm is also acceptable

Comment: If you're going to do a great deal of erases and sequential access, have you considered using a std::list?

Comment: @user4581301 ok..i did not know about std::list, can you please tell me how can I improve my present code using std::list

Comment: For help with improving code, you should really visit http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather than stack overflow.

Comment: It seems taht you copy construct your outer and intter vectors.  That's a lot of memory allocation/deallocation is this really necessary ?

Comment: Using list depends too much on how you are using the vector from which you are deleting in other parts of the code. If all you are doing is adding to the vector, then deleting from it, then list brings much faster removal than vector can offer. If you are doing sifting and sorting, lists suck.

Comment: @Christophe hmmm..you are correct.

Comment: Another idea, rather than std::set_intersection and then remove, why not std::set_difference?

Comment: @user4581301 anything which returns results which are equivalent to those returned by my algorithm works for me :) Nice idea..

Comment: @StegVerner I added some cleanup of your code to my answer and added references to `itm->first` etc rather than capture-by-value for performance. You also don't want to capture `.end()` of a vector you're going to delete from. I did enough to demonstrate the ideas, I'll leave the rest to you :)

Answer (score 15):

There's an underused STL algorithm called `remove_if` that allows you to efficiently (O(n)) remove all elements matching a predicate from a container. It is most useful if you have a `vector` or `deque`, because they have an expensive (O(n)) erase operation for an element "in the middle". However, you need to be aware that `remove_if` doesn't actually erase any element, it only moves all elements that do *not* match the predicate to the front of the range you specified. The canonical way to do an "`erase_if`" is therefore (in this example, all odd integers will be erased):

```
std::vector ints = …;
ints.erase(std::remove_if(begin(ints), end(ints), [](int i) { return i%2 != 0; }), end(ints));
```

Explanation: `remove_if` moves all ints *not* matching the predicate (i.e. the even ints in this example) to the front and returns an iterator one past the last of these elements. Then, we actually erase all elements starting with this one to the end of the vector using the range overload of `vector<int>::erase`.

E.g., assume we have `ints == {5,7,4,10,9,16,20,6}`. `remove_if` will turn `ints` into `{4,10,16,20,6,UNSPEC,UNSPEC,UNSPEC}` where I used `UNSPEC` to denote any unspecified value, and it will also return an iterator pointing to the first `UNSPEC` element. Then, we erase all the elements with unspecified value and get `{4,10,16,20,6}`, the desired result.

UPDATE: With respect to the previous answer, I want to point out that `remove_if` is stable, i.e. it will not change the order of the remaining elements.

Answer (score 6):

The most efficient way to remove an element from a vector is the back-swap trick, but this only applies if you don't care about order.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    auto it = v.begin() + 5;
    // replace the current element with the back of the vector,
    // then shrink the size of the vector by 1.
    *it = std::move(v.back());
    v.pop_back();

    for (auto n : v) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

http://ideone.com/0jbWHZ

If you know there are going to be many deletes or a very large vector, you may retain efficiency by using this trick, remembering not to ++ your current iterator after doing a delete, and `std::sort()`ing the vector when you reach the end.

--- Edit ---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//! Efficiently remove an element from a vector without
//! preserving order. If the element is not the last element
//! in the vector, transfer the last element into its position
//! using a move if possible.
//! Regardless, we then shrink the size of the vector deleting
//! the element at the end, which will either be destructed or
//! the element we were deleting.
//! @note: Effectively invalidates the current iterator.
template<class ValueType>
bool unstable_remove(
    typename std::vector<ValueType>& container,
    typename std::vector<ValueType>::iterator it
    )
{
    // Leave in-situ if we are already the tail element.
    auto lastEl = container.end() - 1;
    if (it != lastEl) {
        // overwrite this element with what is in the last,
        // which should have the same effect as deleting this.
        *it = std::move(*lastEl);
    }
    // release the last cell of the vector, because it should
    // now either be destructed or contain the value we were
    // deleting.
    container.pop_back();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ints { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    auto it = ints.begin();
    while (it != ints.end()) {
        if ((*it % 3) == 0) {
            unstable_remove(ints, it);
            // do not pass go / ++it
            continue;
        }
        ++it;
    }
    std::cout << "after removes:\n";
    for (auto val : ints)
        std::cout << val << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::sort(ints.begin(), ints.end());
    std::cout << "after sort:\n";
    for (auto val : ints)
        std::cout << val << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Produces (http://ideone.com/hGZPOC)

```
after removes:
1 2 10 4 5 8 
after sort:
1 2 4 5 8 10
```

--- Edit 2 ---

Here's a cleanup of your code for readability, I also ditched your end captures because ... you are deleting elements.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

using vec_t = std::vector<uint32_t>;
using vecpair_t = std::pair<vec_t, vec_t>;
using pairvec_t = std::vector<vecpair_t>;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pairvec_t pairV1V2;
    for(auto itm = pairV1V2.begin(); itm != pairV1V2.end(); ++itm)
    {
        //Outer values
        auto& outerV1 = itm->first; // NOTE '&' - reference not copy!
        auto& outerV2 = itm->second;
        sort(outerV2.begin(), outerV2.end());
        for(auto itm2 = itm + 1; itm2 != pairV1V2.end(); ++itm2)
        {
            auto& innerV1 = itm2->first;
            auto& innerV2 = itm2->second;
            vec_t setDiffV1;
```

As for another way to optimize this - since your lists are sorted - walk both lists at the same time comparing values.

```
template<typename ValueType>
void dedupe_vectors(
    typename std::vector<ValueType>& lhs,
    typename std::vector<ValueType>& rhs
    )
{
    auto lit = lhs.begin();
    auto rit = rhs.begin();
    while (rit != rhs.end) {
        while (lit != lhs.end() && *lit < *rit)
            ++lit;
        if (lit == lhs.end())
            break;
        if (*lit == *rit) {
            v2.erase(rit);
            continue;
        }  
        ++rit;
    }
}
```

I know - we test `lit` vs `lhs.end` twice. Take a look at the code your compiler generates with -O3 and see if it doesn't detect this itself. If so, then you can worry about optimizing it.

Comment: Or if you don't care about order and it's possible to make the change, consider `std::unordered_set`.