# How to delete specific elements in a vector using struct data type

Tags: c++, vector, struct

i'm new to C++. My program is a quiz game which user can choose category and level for the questions. At first, i use the struct data type

```
struct QuestionInfo
{
   string category;
   string level;
   string question;
   string answer; 
};
```

then

```
vector<QuestionInfo> vec;
```

The idea of this part is to store the info of the question include (category, level, question and answer) to each element.
Then after building menu and the output questions UI, i go to the filters

```
void category_filter()
{
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i ++)
   {
      if (category_choice != vec[i].category)
         vec.erase(vec.begin() + i );
   }
}
Void level_filter()
{
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i ++)
   {
      if (level_choice != vec[i].level)
         vec.erase(vec.begin() + i );
   }
}
```

So the idea of the filters is to delete the elements which not contain the matched category and level. But the output questions did not match with the category and the level i had choose before.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain you the problem with my example. Suppose you have a vector of `10` elements, valid indexes are `0` till `9` elements. You have to erase 5th element `i == 4`. You erase it, then 6th element with index `5` moves to place of 5th elements with index `4`. After that you increase `i` in `for`, it becomes `5`. Thus you skip previous 6th element, that is now 5th with index `4`.

You may fix your code like below, moving `i ++` to the condition.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ) {
    if (category_choice != vec[i].category)
        vec.erase(vec.begin() + i );
    else
        i ++;
}
```

The preferable solution in C++ way is demonstrated by @Jonathan.

Comment: Please post your updated code. Maybe there are typos.

Comment: `void category_filter(vector <QuestionInfo> vec,string category_choice)
{
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size();)
     {
        if (category_choice != vec[i].category)
            vec.erase(vec.begin() + i );
        else
            i++;
     }
}`


`void level_filter(vector <QuestionInfo> vec,string  level_choice )
{
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size();)
   {
        if (level_choice != vec[i].level)
            vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
        else
            i++;
   }
}`

Comment: Sorry, I did not noticed it before. Your functions work with vector copies. Please add references `&` to the parameters `vec`.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting tripped up by not accounting for the indexing shift that occurs when you erase an element. I personally would rely on [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) with a lambda to accomplish this:

```
vec.erase(remove_if(begin(vec), end(vec), [&](const auto& i) { return category_choice != i.category; }, end(vec));
vec.erase(remove_if(begin(vec), end(vec), [&](const auto& i) { return level_choice != i.level; }, end(vec));
```

Alternatively you might consider combining them for a bit of speed improvement:

```
vec.erase(remove_if(begin(vec), end(vec), [&](const auto& i) { return category_choice != i.category || level_choice != i.level; }, end(vec));
```

Comment: When i replace my erase function by your code, i got the error `begin was not declared in this scope`. Also when i change your code to this `vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const auto& i) { return category_choice != v[i].category; }, vec.end());` i got another error `no matching function for call to remove_if`. I don't know what is wrong here

Comment: @Kenny That just means that your compiler is not C++11 compliant. If you're using gcc for example you could enable that with the `-std=c++11` flag. But in lieu of a C++11 compliant compiler you can just use the substitution in your comment. As far as the reasons the `remove_if` wouldn't exist, that's either because you haven't done: `#include <algorithm>` or because you're not `using namespace std`, in which case you'd just want to call `std::remove_if`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to remove_if + erase:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    struct QuestionInfo
    {
        std::string category;
        std::string level;
        std::string question;
        std::string answer;
        QuestionInfo(std::string category, std::string level, std::string question, std::string answer) :
            category(category), level(level), question(question), answer(answer) {}
    };

    std::vector<QuestionInfo> vec;
    std::string category_choice = "cat1";
    std::string level_choice = "lev1";

    vec.push_back(QuestionInfo("cat1", "lev1", "q1", "a1"));
    vec.push_back(QuestionInfo("cat1", "lev2", "q2", "a2"));
    vec.push_back(QuestionInfo("cat2", "lev1", "q3", "a3"));
    vec.push_back(QuestionInfo("cat2", "lev2", "q4", "a4"));

    std::cout << "\nNot filered" << std::endl;
    for (auto const &info : vec)
        std::cout << "Category:" << info.category << " Level:" << info.level << std::endl;

    auto filter_category = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](auto const &info) {return category_choice != info.category; });
    vec.erase(filter_category, vec.end());

    std::cout << "\nFilered by category" << std::endl;
    for (auto const &info : vec)
        std::cout << "Category:" << info.category << " Level:" << info.level << std::endl;

    auto filter_level = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](auto const &info) {return level_choice != info.level; });
    vec.erase(filter_level, vec.end());

    std::cout << "\nFiltered by level" << std::endl;
    for (auto const &info : vec)
        std::cout << "Category:" << info.category << " Level:" << info.level << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the `remove_if` + `erase` is a standard and expressive way to achieve what you want. But you may also consider non-destructive filtering with a `copy_if` into a new container, or even without using any additional storage with Boost.Range adaptor `boost::adaptors::filtered` or [boost::filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204676/modern-way-to-filter-stl-container) for examples.